# how to set windows 7 to it's basic state

Tags: windows-7

I want to set my Windows 7 the minimum basic state. I want to keep only the services and configuration that allow direct-show apps(media), CD burning, and printing to function.

So appreciate any info, and advises.

Comment: Maybe some check these out if this is what you are looking for you will have to be the judge of what you want to keep. [Here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/218323/speed_up_windows_by_stripping_it_down.html) and [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-windows-7-services-you-may-not-need/) is this the content you are looking for?

Comment: Here is another which will help you speed the system up. [Here](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow_viewer/0,3253,l=251692&a=251692&po=4,00.asp)